# How to define a data model for the following requirement in C++

Tags: design-patterns, datamodel

define the connectivity between objects and its metadata. The connectivity could be directed or undirected , bi directional.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you add more details? Adding what you have already tried would help any future answerers.

Comment: I have not tried anything , since i am unable to understand how do i proceed for defining such a data model.